# How do I create a while loop in java that will end the game once the two user inputs match?

Tags: java, while-loop, user-input

I have been trying to create a game that asks the user to type in 2 three-letter words; the program is supposed to give clues for how close the words match by splitting them up and stating if the letters come before, or after, each other in the alphabet.

The game is nearly done, but my problem shows up when I try to start a new turn after one guess. I need some kind of while loop, but I've rearranged blocks of the code so many times that I feel like it made the entire thing more convoluted. The prompt for the second user to answer a question, as well as the clue, should be repeated every time the two inputs don't fully match.

> Example Output when the two user inputs are cat and fan: after, a, before

> The "after" shows that the letter comes after the user's letter in the alphabet, and the "before" shows that the letter comes before the user's letter.

**EDIT**: *I have taken the answers into account as much as I can, thank you so much.* *So far, I have implemented a do while loop and tried to fix my variables.* *In the end, I feel that I may have to create an object to be able to recopy the code of the user inputs after a certain conditional statement would be set to false.*

*My new issues are*

*1. The compiler cannot find the symbols x1,y1,z1,x2,y2, and z2 whenever I have the user inputs inside the do while loop.*

*2. If I tried to make a new object, I would be rewriting & rearranging more than what might be necessary.*
*This is still ongoing, and as I continue to work on it I will keep updating this post.*

(**EDITED CODE** -- I saved the original code which I can send to anyone who would like to see it.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Guess The Word\n(requires two players)");
    System.out.println("If the letter in each word matches, the letter will be reprinted.");
    System.out.println("If the letter guessed doesn't match, either \"before\" or \"after\" will print.");
    Scanner in1=new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner in2=new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
      boolean correct1=false; boolean correct2=false; boolean correct3=false;
      int indication=0;
//asks for user input and stores in substrings
      do{
      System.out.print("First Player, enter a three letter word: ");
      String user1=in1.nextLine();
      String x1=user1.substring(0,1);
      String y1=user1.substring(1,2);
      String z1=user1.substring(2,3);
      System.out.print("Second Player, enter a three letter word: ");
      String user2=in1.nextLine();
      String x2=user2.substring(0,1);
      String y2=user2.substring(1,2);
      String z2=user2.substring(2,3);
      }
      while(!correct1||!correct2||!correct3);
//possible end to loop
//      if(user1==user2){indication=1;}
//      else{indication=0;}
//comparisons of each letter
      int comp;
      int comp2;
      int comp3;
      comp=x1.compareTo(x2);
      comp2=y1.compareTo(y2);
      comp3=z1.compareTo(z2);
        //while1=(comp!=0);
        //while2=(comp2!=0);
        //while3=(comp3!=0);
//if statement 1
      if(comp==0){
        System.out.print(x1);
        correct1=true;
      }
      else{
//        System.out.println(comp);
        if(comp>0){
          System.out.println("before, ");
        }
        else{
          System.out.print("after, ");
        }
      }
//if statement 2
      if(comp2==0){
        System.out.print(y1);
        correct2=true;
      }
      else{
//        System.out.println(comp);
        if(comp2>0){
          System.out.println(", before, ");
        }
        else{
          System.out.print(", after, ");
        }
      }
//if statement 3
      if(comp3==0){
        System.out.print(z1);
        correct3=true;
      }
      else{
//        System.out.println(comp3);
        if(comp3>0){
          System.out.println(", before");
        }
        else{
          System.out.print(", after");
        }
      }
         //ignore else{System.out.print("Congratulations!");}
    }
    finally{in1.close();}/* in2.close();}*/
  }
  }
```

Comment: A couple things unrelated to your problem - you don't need 2 Scanners both reading from the same input stream, and `var` is a keyword in Java 10+, so you probably want a more descriptive name. As for the loop itself, I guess you could have some boolean `same` that's set to false initially and set to true only when the 2 inputs are equal. Then you do `do {/*ask for input*/} while (!same)`

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't known I could use one Scanner for both, that simplifies things a lot. I made sure to change the variable as well even though I decided not to use it, and I'll keep note of var being a keyword for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe declare 3 booleans (1IsCorrect, 2IsCorrect, 3IsCorrect) set them default to false and in the if(comp/comp1/comp2 == 0) statements after printing the value set the corresponding boolean to true.
then put it in a do while(!1IsCorrect || !2IsCorrect || !3IsCorrect)
declare a variable perhaps for isFirstRun before loop and instantiate it to true at the declaration, then set to false at the very end.
Make an if !isFirstRun statement and add in the code there to ask for the next guess

Hope this works

Comment: This helps a ton! I never thought of using a do while loop before, so I made sure to do that first. I may possibly try creating an object for the code so that it wouldn't have to be copied at the end, but I have been going a bit out of my own depth and this entire post has been a learning process for me. I'll be trying to implement the isFirstRun statements in some way next.

Comment: That aounds great! With the isFirstRun, you could use it to keep asking only player 2 to try guessing until they get it right which could add some functionality to printing before and after. Also practice naming variables, such as the x1 y1 etc could be P1Letter1 and P2Letter1 etc. (avoid using x/y/z) And you could shove in the compare statements into the if statement so no need for the comp variable. Also conventional to cal your Scanner scanner or scan just for clarity